# passing multiple variables through format SAS

Tags: sas

The following code creates the below table.

```
proc format;
value income_format
low -< 0 = "low"
1 -< 30 = "low-medium"
30 -< 60 = "average"
60 -< 90 = "high"
90 - high = "excellent";
run;



proc freq data = lib1.all;
format income income_format.; /* assign IncomeFmt format to Income variable */
tables income
/OUT = income_table outcum ;
run;
```

[image: table]

however I want to group this data by date, I have monthly data. So I added a DATE format in the `format` line. However when I do this I just get returned the exact same table, why is this?

```
proc freq data = lib1.all;
    format income income_format. DATE YYMMD7.; /* assign IncomeFmt format to Income variable and dateformat to date variable */
    tables income
    /OUT = income_table outcum ;
    run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` only tells SAS how to display something to you. Since you want to make frequency tables by date, you need to use the `by` statement. Be sure to sort or index your data by date first.

```
proc freq data = lib1.all;
    format income income_format. DATE YYMMD7.; /* assign IncomeFmt format to Income variable and dateformat to date variable */
    by date;

    tables income /OUT = income_table outcum ;
run;
```